# Web service to fetch data return null in ios 6 but not in ios 7

Tags: iphone, web-services, ios6, ios7, xcode5

I am consuming Web Service to fetch data and it returns a set of data from server, this works great before i install xcode 5, previously my app was compatible with ios6 now i changed to ios 7. Now i have one issue while fetching data from web service .

When i go first time to the UIViewController view i call web service in -(void)ViewDidLoad and no data return and if i call one more time ( without going back from view, i call again the same web service) it returns data, when i call first time it returns empty data but second time it return data, This is happening in ios 6 but the same code work perfect without any web service issue in ios 7. after i change

I am Receiving response from server but the data inside is null for first time, but the same time i run in ios 7 device its return data, so i don't understand where i am wrong??????

```
 NSMutableData *serverData;
 //delegate methods for NSURLConnection
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
      NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:serverData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];//here i am initializing 
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
      [serverData appendData:data]; // here i get data that is null but i get response from server

}



Myviewwillappear code here...
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[self performSelector:@selector(GetDataFromServer) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.001];
}
- (void) GetDataFromServer {
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"

                         @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"

                         @"<soap:Body>"

                         @"<GetProductList xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"

                         @"<inCompany>%@</inCompany>"

                         @"<inUserName>%@</inUserName>"

                         @"<inType>%@</inType>"

                         @"<inTypeValue>%@</inTypeValue>"

                         @"<inSearchVal>%@</inSearchVal>"

                         @"<inPage>%@</inPage>"

                         @"</GetProductList>"

                         @"</soap:Body>"

                         @"</soap:Envelope>",Company,Username,type,typevalue,searchval,page];



NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:PVBASE_URL];

NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapMessage length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request addValue:PVPRODUCTLIST forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[request setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (connection) {



    if (serverData) {



        serverData = nil;

    }

    serverData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

}

connection = nil;
}
```

Comment: can you please post some related code snippets?

Comment: @CarlJ i added my code in question i receive response from server but inside the xml tag data is null for first time next time getting data so whenever i go to that view first time return data contain null in ios 6 device and i tested in ios 7 device also i didn't face any issue like this. So can you tell me where i am wrong????

Comment: I am having an issue related in that my didReceiveResponse function gets a response from the server, but no data attached.  In the headers there is no content length?  This functionality worked great in iOS 6, but in iOS 7 and Xcode 5, I get this issue.  I would love to hear more?

Answer (score 0):

Basically i have en-counted this issue several times as when ever **viewDidLoad** execute didn't get any data but explicit call from **IBaction** it does. this is nothing to deal with iOS. basic problem with your web-service call.

You might be be calling data with using public variable which not execute or initialize.
Please provide your code for better understanding.

Thanks !!

Comment: Yes i face this issue before, data return from server sometimes empty, and i solve that issue by initializing it.I will add code in my question please go through it.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would share my answer here as a possible solution.  I had a similar problem occur with iOS6 and when I upgraded to iOS7 the network stack appeared to not be working because I was not getting data on the didRecieveResponse function of NSURLConnection.  When in actuality from comparing how my code acted between iOS platforms it only looked like I was not receiving data from the didRecieveResponse function because sometimes the expectedContentLength mostly returned -1, but this also happened in iOS 6.  In iOS7 the problem originated from another source that is unrelated to this example or my network connection that was affecting my use of NSOperation.  So my point is, possibly the problem is not your platform differences but your code running your functionality.  I would go through your code again for errors.